# Can i use unzip session in workflow when the file is a .txt file

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on an Informatica workflow and using Teradata Database. The file is a .txt file.
When I run the workflow I get the error message below.
Error opening file [/infa_shared/uss/SrcFiles/vnd_MG//PRx]. Operating system error message [no such file or directory].
I have an unzip session in the sessions.

Comment: When yoou unzip - is it unzipping in correct location? Are you passing that location to your infa paramm file? It should be a list if its a pattern like PR*.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a command task to execute the unzip explicitly.
If your file name is PRx.txt, then the command line of the task will be:

```
unzip /infa_shared/uss/SrcFiles/vnd_MG//PRx.txt
```

Then in the next connected session, associate the source file with the filename you have extracted from your .txt archive  - in your session's mapping setting.

Comment: In the parameter file, I have

Comment: In the parameter file, I have.  $param_SrcFile_Dir=/infa_shared/USS/SrcFiles/vnd_MG so I decided to add //PRx*.txt because there are other characters after Rx but it is still failing with the same error message

Comment: Try to do this explicitly first - to see if this works without the parameter SrcDir, like: unzip <source_dir>/filemask*.txt

Comment: Thanks, i asked my boss and he said from what he understands, the client usually uses only .txt files , so i decided to delete the unzip session from the session workflow and it is working now. Thanks for your suggestion.